# How do i prevent phone zoom on multi click over canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, click

I am making a flappy bird app and I want my flappy bird to work correctly on phone but when i play on phone I have to click fast and when I click fast my phone zooms in. How do I prevent this thing to happen?

Here's my app - http://ivaylonikolov.net/flappybird/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to ur head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```